# lua pattern, exclusion doesn't work with end of string

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

Maybe exclusion is not the correct term, but I'm talking about using the following in lua's string.find() function :

```
[^exclude]
```

It doesn't seem to work if the character is followed by nothing, IE it's the last character in the string.

More specifically, I'm getting a list of processes running and attempting to parse them internally with LUA.

```
root@OpenWrt:/# ps | grep mpd
 5427 root     21620 S    mpd /etc/mpd2.conf
 5437 root     25660 S    mpd
```

This wouldn't be an issue if I could expect a \n every time, but sometimes ps doesn't list itself which creates this issue. I want to match:

```
5437 root     25660 S    mpd
```

From this I will extract the PID for a kill command. I'm running an OpenWRT build that doesn't support regex or exact options on killall otherwise I'd just do that.

```
(%d+ root%s+%d+ S%s+mpd[^ ])
```

The above pattern does not work unfortunately. It's because there is no character after the last character in the last line I believe. I have also tried these:

```
(%d+ root%s+%d+ S%s+mpd$)
```

The above pattern returns nil.

```
(%d+ root%s+%d+ S%s+mpd[^ ]?)
```

The above pattern returns the first process (5427)

Maybe there is a better way to go about this, or just a simple pattern change I can make to get it to work, but I can't seem to find one that will only grab the right process. I can't go off PID or VSZ since they are variable. Maybe I'll have to see if I can compile OpenWRT with better killall support.

Anyways, thanks for taking the time to read this, and if this is a duplicate I'm sorry but I couldn't find anything similar to my predicament. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `pgrep` available? It might help. That `$` pattern should match though. What's the looping code you have doing the match?

Comment: I have pgrep, doesn't seem to work. It returns both mpd processes. The code I have is just a javascript button that sends an http post to my openwrt router, which has LUA interactions based on the post data. So it's essentially just a button to kill mpd, but I don't want to kill mpd /etc/mpd2.conf as that is a music streamer and I only want to kill the local player. I'm not even using it to test though, i'm just ssh'd into my router running LUA interactively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given:

```
local s = [[5427 root     21620 S    mpd /etc/mpd2.conf
5437 root     25660 S    mpd]]
```

The following pattern

```
string.match(s,"(%d+)%s+root%s+%d+%s+S%s+mpd[%s]-$")
```

returns: 
5437 root     25660 S    mpd

whereas this:

```
string.match(s,"(%d+%s+root%s+%d+%s+S%s+mpd[%s]%p?[%w%p]+)")
```

returns:

5427 root     21620 S    mpd /etc/mpd2.conf

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much for your help! If I'm trying to understand why it seems the [%s]- means 0 or 1 space, not sure what the [] is for though, and the $ signifies the end of the line.